# Characters Array

Tags: java, char

I am trying to print every second letter in the string but for some reason I only print the first second letter correctly but after that it keeps printing in a weird order. Here is my code:

```
    out.print("Please enter a word: ");
    String word = in.nextLine();
    char[] c = word.toCharArray();
    int x = 0;
    while (x < c.length) {
        if (c[x] % 2 != 0) {
            out.print(word.charAt(x) + " ");
        }

        x++;
    }
```

Comment: A while loop and modulo operator might not be best suited for this. Try for-loop.

Comment: `if (c[x] % 2 != 0)` should be `if (x % 2 != 0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change this:

```
if (c[x] % 2 != 0) {
```

to

```
if (x % 2 != 0) {
```

This compares the index you are working with instead of comparing the character. `x` is the position of the character. `c[x]` is the character. You can read `c[x]` as "the value at position `x` in array `c`".

Comment: So c[x] isn't the position of the character?

Comment: @KennethFaried: It is the character itself. `x` indicates the index.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you attempting to determine if the character (`c[x]`) is odd?  You should be testing the index itself.

```
if (x % 2 != 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the character modulo 2 instead of the *index* modulo 2

By the way:

```
String word …
for(int ix=1; ix<word.length(); ix+=2)
    out.print(word.charAt(ix) + " ");
```

makes it far simpler.

Comment: Which is better to use while loops or for loops? I have always used while loops when I program..!!

Comment: @KennethFaried. If you know the limit of the number of iteration, then for loop is mostly better option. In this case, for loop is much clearer.

Comment: Use `for` loops if you have either an initialization instruction or an “update for repeat” instruction or even both. Here you have both, `int ix=1` and `ix+=2` clearly exist for loop maintenance and nothing else.  So it’s best put into a `for`loop.

Comment: Also in this case, for loop will iterate half the number of times the while loop. Wouldn't matter by even measurable difference, but still.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: Yes, but you could still write a `while` loop doing exactly the same. But that’s not recommended as it makes it harder to tell the real loop body apart from loop bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

Problem area: You are checking value instead of index

```
while (x < c.length) {
        if (c[x] % 2 != 0) {
            out.print(word.charAt(x) + " ");
        }
```

Convert it to: Checking index instead of value

```
   while (x < c.length) {
            if (x % 2 != 0) {
                out.print(word.charAt(x) + " ");
            }
```